# React Native: RNGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation - Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: ios, react-native, geocoding

i tried to implement this react native component ([react-native-geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder)) into my current app and get the following error:

```
[]([warn][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Possible Unhandled Promise 

Rejection (id: 0):
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation')
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:61745:11
tryCallTwo@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:2626:3
doResolve@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:2781:19
Promise@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:2647:10
reverseGeocodeLocation@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:61743:19
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:15334:34
requireImpl@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:76:17
requireImpl@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:44:30
_require@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:36:19
global code@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true:61774:9
)
```

my code

```
var RNGeocoder = require('react-native-geocoder');

// Reverse Geocoding
var NY = {
  latitude: 40.7809261,
  longitude: -73.9637594
};

RNGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(NY, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

Is there any setting issue on my setup? I use the newest react native version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot include the libRNGeocoder.a in your project. Have you added it like written in the component's ?

> 1. In the XCode's "Project navigator", right click on Libraries folder under your project ➜ Add Files to <...>
> 2. Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-geocoder and add the RNGeocoder.xcodeproj file
> 3. Add libRNGeocoder.a to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries